# UNIT Test Error: No Contract deployed with name Raffle

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, solidity

This is the section of my unit testing... I've been working on this problem for the last few hours. I couldn't, however... I think the error is in
`const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts()` this line. Raffle contract isn't recognized... (Note- All the deployments are working correctly... )

```
    !developmentChains.includes(network.name)
        ? describe.skip()
        : describe("Raffle UNIT test", async () => {
              let raffle, vrfCoordinatorV2Mock
              const chainId = network.config.chainId
              beforeEach(async () => {
                  const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts()
                  await deployments.fixture(["all"])
                  raffle = await ethers.getContract("Raffle", deployer)
                  vrfCoordinatorV2Mock = await ethers.getContract("VRFCoordinatorV2Mock", deployer)
              })
              describe("Constructor function", async () => {
                  it("Initializes the raffle correctly.", async () => {
                      const raffleState = await raffle.getRaffleState()
                      const interval = await raffle.getInterval()
    
                      assert.equal(raffleState.toString(), "0")
                      assert.equal(interval.toString(), networkConfig[chainId]["interval"])
                  })
              })
          })
```

ERROR that I got...

```
 ~/b/JSweb3_2/smart-contract_lottery  on main !2  hh test                                                      ✔  took 5s  system    at 07:27:25 am 


  Raffle UNIT test
    Constructor function
Development chain detected! Deploying mocks
Mocks deployed!!!...
---------------------!--!--!---------------------
      1) "before each" hook for "Initializes the raffle correctly."
  0 passing (428ms)
  1 failing

  1) Raffle UNIT test
       "before each" hook for "Initializes the raffle correctly.":
     Error: No Contract deployed with name Raffle
      at Object.getContract (node_modules/@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers/src/internal/helpers.ts:447:11)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
      at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:65:3)
      at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:528:9)
      at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/unit/Raffle.test.js:16:24)
```

I AM FOLLOWING A CORDING TUTOTIAL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're following Patrick's course, have you checked if your deploy scripts are executing or not before running tests? You can do console logs in scripts and be sure that they are exporting tags. for example,

```
module.exports.tags = ['all', 'mocks'];
```

Comment: Yes, I've checked... All the deployments are working fine and the Contract name is also Raffle... but, it doesn't recognise the tests...

Comment: `Nothing to compile
Development chain detected! Deploying mocks
deploying "VRFCoordinatorV2Mock" (tx: 0x11b9dfa83e5a81e783d8d818bd6499fa1504a937113eca5f07b8cfafe70751ea)...: deployed at 0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3 with 1797707 gas
Mocks deployed!!!...
---------------------!--!--!---------------------
deploying "Raffle" (tx: 0xed22e49fa63df9be9b15bef6124076fd1cd31661cf3d6da327db7d3383a10539)...: deployed at 0xCf7Ed3AccA5a467e9e704C703E8D87F634fB0Fc9 with 1210604 gas
-----------!!!!!------!!!!!---!!!!!-----!!!!!----------`

Comment: It will be easy to check If you can share code via GitHub repo or any other means.

Comment: [Github link] (https://github.com/uzair011/Lottery-random-JS)

Comment: You need to bring [this](https://github.com/uzair011/Lottery-random-JS/blob/main/deploy/01-deploy-raffle.js#L52) line at the bottom/out of the deploy script. 


}
module.exports.tags = ["all", "raffle"]

Comment: Thank you very much; I hadn't noticed that.

Comment: My pleasure, You can ask your doubts in the [discussion](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/full-blockchain-solidity-course-js/discussions) section of the course. You will get more help there. Happy Learning.

Comment: @BhavikChavda Danké

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem, during Patrick's course and I've changed `getContract("ContractName", deployer)` with

```js
getContractAt("ContractName", deployer)
```

and it works. I am a beginner and I don't believe it to be the correct way.

I found an explanation of different `getContract` variants in [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77887937/12015105).

I figured out the probable cause of this error (still on Patrick's course): if you run `yarn hardhat run scripts/fund.js` it might display this error because you are trying to find the contract on the hardhat network.

But if you run it with the `--network` flag:

```bash
yarn hardhat run scripts/fund.js --network localhost
```

It will work, because the contract, you've just deployed is there. If you are following closely with Patrick's course, you would have 2 networks in the `helper-hardhat-config.js`:

```js
const developmentChains = ["hardhat", "localhost"];
```